# getting error while fetching id from list button url

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, case-object

I have created a list button which is mapped to vf page **/apex/NewProblem**, This button i made visible on case related list of problem object. 
[image]

So whenever i remove the id from button url it is showing vf page as given below but issue is when i pass case id into url it is giving me error as **"Id value 5001q00000174vD is not valid for the SC_Problem_Management__c standard controller"** . I am passing this value because it should appear on Case field of vf page. But it is not doing so, i have tried many times to resolve it facing same issue again and again.

vf page snap:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to arrange for a different variable to be used. The `id` parameter is always reserved for the standard controller.

## URL

```
/apex/NewProblem?caseId={!Case.Id}
```

## Page

```
<apex:page standardController="SC_Problem_Management__c" extensions="PM_Controller" ...
```

## Controller

```
public with sharing class PM_Controller {
  ApexPages.StandardController sc;
  public PM_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController con) {
    sc = con;
    SC_Problem_Management__c record = (SC_Problem_Management__c)con.getRecord();
    record.Case__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('caseId');
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. i was getting error because of id parameter which is resolved now.